# Rails: Extracting the raw url from the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with Rails 2.2.

The required behaviour is as follows:

I have a link(with a ajax link embedded)

xyz.com/admin#page1

When I go to the above page, I should be redirected to the login page, if I am not logged in.

After I log in, I should be taken back to

xyz.com/admin#page1

For this I need to store the url in session when I visit any page.

The problem is that when I do request.uri, I get
xyz.com/admin

But I want to store
xyz.com/admin#page1

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

# params don't send to server, so if you want to store # params you should [save it in javascript to cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp)