# How can I parse the `access_token` from a Facebook callback URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, request

This is the request Facebook calls back:

```
/facebook/promo/#access_token=162592277090170%7C2.yCch3otjrdit_rgBFS6F0A__.3600.1285369200-727781553%7CtugQmoO0bRiadumHVQrrSiPRD9Y&expires_in=7174
```

How can I parse the `access_token` from the URL? I could not find any way to get the `access_token` value.

Please be aware that it is not a reqular parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex to match it out of the url. Or simply take everything as a sub-string between `access_token=` and the next `&`-character or the end of the url, which ever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's not possible - the part after # is simply ignored. See this answer: [Rails: Extracting the raw url from the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651080/rails-extracting-the-raw-url-from-the-request)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after the `access_token=...` section, just use some simple string matching:

```
url = '/facebook/promo/#access_token=162592277090170%7C2.yCch3otjrdit_rgBFS6F0A__.3600.1285369200-727781553%7CtugQmoO0bRiadumHVQrrSiPRD9Y&expires_in=7174'
url[/#access_token=(.+)&/, 1]
=> "162592277090170%7C2.yCch3otjrdit_rgBFS6F0A__.3600.1285369200-727781553%7CtugQmoO0bRiadumHVQrrSiPRD9Y"
```

That looks for `#access_token=` and grabs everything up to `&`.